# pure-ftpd working but leaving open processes for every login

Tags: high-sierra, ftp

I recently jumped from OSX El Capitan to High Sierra. One of the things I lost was my FTP server, which is used by my in-house webcam system to record events. When El Capitan went away, so did my recording ability.

So, after much effort and hair pulling, I finally got pure-ftpd running and working fine. But, every time one of my cameras --even the same camera-- logs in to the server it leaves an open process. With each login to record creating a new process, eventually the server is reduced to a crawl and video is no longer able to be written; I get lots of 0k files started but nothing written to them.

I'm only guessing at that last turn of events. If I flush the queue of open processes and restart the FTP server, everything runs as expected for a while. But, currently I have 103 open instances of process name 'pure-ftpd'. Aproximately half of them are my login user name and the other half root. only 6 are using CPU, the rest are at 0%. The same active processes are using about 1mb of memory. But, the rest are all using about 500k, or about 60mb total.

This never happened with the FTP server bundled with OSX prior to High Sierra. Is there a setting in pure-ftpd I need to change so that these processes zombies don't linger?

Comment: Would it be possible for your webcam to use sftp instead of ftp? I ask because macOS comes with the built-in ability to start an sftp server, just enable remote login in System Preferences → Sharing.

Comment: I had to look. Unfortunately, no. Just FTP. I tried forcing SFTP credentials in to the FTP fields. But, after some reading on other forums, it looks like only FTP is supported (Amcrest IP camera FWIW)
In the meantime I've set a cron script to flush the purftpd process every hour. So far that seems to keep the open processes to 10-15 or so.